# In Woocommerce, How to find all products for which a certain product is a cross-sell?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I would like to get a list of products that a certain product is defined as a cross-sell for them.

So checking for which products B is a cross-sell would give: A, C

Didn't find any background for this

Example:
product A has products B, C as cross sells
Product B has products A, C, D as cross sells
Product C has products A, B, D as cross sells

So checking for which products B is a cross-sell would give: A, C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with mysql query.

As WooCommerce stores crosssell IDs as serialized data - correct way seems to be reading all products via some WP loop and unserialize->analyze all crosssell IDs then search for the needed ID - but it would take too much time and memory.

That's why we need to find easier way - some trick. Here it is:

Assume ID of product A is 132, product B is 60, product C is 34.

And product A has 2 crosssell products - B and C.

So wp_postmeta table would have such row:

```
1098    132 _crosssell_ids  a:2:{i:0;i:60;i:1;i:34;}
```

Product B present's in other products' crossell_ids meta data as a "i:60;" unique string. That's why we just need to look for that string acroos all wp_postmeta.

```
global $wpdb;
$product_b_id=60;

$product_that_have_B_as_crossell= $wpdb->get_col("select post_id 
from $wpdb->postmeta 
where 
meta_key='_crosssell_ids' 
and
meta_value like  '%i:".esc_sql($product_b_id).";%' ");

var_dump($product_that_have_B_as_crossell);
```